"How Can I Manage My Token at the Lowest Cost?"
I own a token at this address: https://dexscreener.com/solana/GdhovaWSEGk6sqMiu6WFZ9314Fs39p4Pv4ZK6HGxwVrL.
I created this token using Smithi, but no matter what you add to the token, you have to pay a fee. What should I do to manage it myself and at the lowest cost?
